# How can I check if user is signed in with rails devise?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I am trying to add the header to my rails application based on authenticating the user. So here I am checking that if the user has logged in or signed in and then adding login/logout link based on that.

But I am getting the following error:

```
application.html.erb:16: syntax error, unexpected tSYMBEG, expecting keyword_do or '{' or '(' ...roy_user_session_path, method :delete );@output_buffer.safe_
```

Here's what I have tried:

```
<% if user_signed_in? do %> 
    <%= link_to "Log out", destroy_user_session_path, method :delete %>
<% else %>
    <%= link_to "login", new_user_session_path %>
<% end %>
```

How can I resolve this?

Comment: it should be `<%= link_to "Log out", destroy_user_session_path, method: :delete %>` and remove `do`

Comment: atleast mark the answer correct

Answer (score 43, accepted):

First of all remove `do` from this line, you don't need that

```
<% if user_signed_in? %>
```

Secondly add `:` after `method`, it's a key value pair

```
<%= link_to "Log out", destroy_user_session_path, method: :delete %>
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for *and* it worked! Thank you!

Answer (score 6):

You are making a syntax error in method delete. Copy the below code

```
<% if user_signed_in? %>
    <%= link_to "Log out", destroy_user_session_path, :method=>'delete'%>
<% else %>
    <%= link_to "login", new_user_session_path %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using devise, use the `current_user` helper. Of course, this depends on what you called your initial `user` model.

```
<% if current_user %>
    You're logged in!
<% else %>
    Not logged in.
<% end %>
```